# Minimum time for two people to finish $n$ tasks, no task done simultaneously

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following task: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1631.

Essentially, there are two people Kotivalo and Justiina who are going to read $n$ books which take times $t_1, t_2 \ldots t_n$ to read respectively. I want to produce a reading schedule for both of them that allows all the books to be read by both of them with neither of them reading the same book at the same time.
This may involve some period of time where one of them is not reading any book.

Apparently, the answer is $\max(\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i, 2T)$ where $T = \max_{i \in \{1, 2, \ldots n\}}\{t_i\}$.
The reasoning that I have seen is that if $T \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n t_i - T$ then the longest book has to be read by both of them separately, taking $2T$ time. While the other is reading the longest book, each of them can read the entirety of the rest of the books completely.

However, I can't show that if the reverse inequality holds, i.e. $T < \sum_{i = 1}^nt_i-T$, then there exists some schedule that allows all the books to be read in time $\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i$ without any time instant where both of them are reading the same book.

Comment: "I just had a look at your profile: you have never validated the answers that have been given to you. This is not the way this site works." Someone said to you long ago. It seems you rarely if ever vote for good answers to your answer nor accepting them. Who will write answers to your questions?